Error: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
This is the code:
function getCURL($url, $decode = '', $data = '', $headers = '', $timeout='') {

    global $_SERVER;

    $ch = curl_init();

    if($timeout){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    if(is_array($data)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    if(is_array($headers)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($response === false) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $response = ($decode == true)? json_decode($response,true) : $response;

        if($decode == true){ $response['httpcode'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); }
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

    $token = substr(md5(time().$_SESSION['auth_user']['username']),0,25);
    // Format API Link
    $alias = 'ADR'.randHash(12);
    $long_url = "{$urlweb}/shortlinks/{$token}";
    $api_token = "b644192e44dded8871e867747698bea4d2ce6b8e";

    $api_url = str_replace('?api={apikey}&url={url}', '?api={apikey}&alias={alias}&url={url}', $sldata[$shortlinkname]['apilink']);
    $api_url = str_replace(array('{apikey}', '{url}', '{alias}'),  array($sldata[$shortlinkname]['apitoken'], $long_url, $alias), $api_url);

    // Get Shortlink
    $shortlink = getCURL($api_url);
    $shortlink = (strstr($shortlink,'":"'))? current(preg_grep('~^http~',json_decode($shortlink,true))) : trim($shortlink);

    if(!strpos($shortlink, 'api/') && !strpos($shortlink, 'api.php')  && filter_var($shortlink, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        $_SESSION['auth_user']['sl']['link_id'] = $shortlinkname;
        $_SESSION['auth_user']['sl']['token'] = $token;
        $_SESSION['auth_user']['sl']['link'] = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", $shortlink);
        $_SESSION['auth_user']['sl']['time'] = time();
        header("Location: $shortlink");
        exit;
    }

This return the error: Error: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
The website I am asking for a response is https, this will give me a json, where that json has an http link, I don't know if that affects it, this works for me with other links, but with this one it returns that.
I use AutoSSL
